# call custom python function on every document in a collection Mongo DB

Tags: mongodb, pymongo, pymongo-3.x

I want to call a custom python function on some existing attribute of every document in the entire collection *and* store the result as a new key-value pair in that (same) document. May I know if there's any way to do that (since each call is independent of others) ?

I noticed `cursor.forEach` but can't it be done just using python efficiently ?

A simple example would be to split the string in `text` and store the no. of words as a new attribute.

```
def split_count(text):
    # some complex preprocessing...

    return len(text.split())

# Need something like this...
db.collection.update_many({}, {'$set': {"split": split_count('$text') }}, upsert=True)
```

But it seems like setting a new attribute in a document based on the value of another attribute in the same document is [not possible](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3976218/3282392) this way yet. This post is old but the issues seem to be still open.

Comment: can you post some example code of what you're wanting to do?

Comment: did my answer solve this?

Comment: @SteveRossiter uhh.. yes & no. It solves the current task (splitting the text) but I also want to call _any_ python function which makes me difficult to stick only to _JS_ approach. Also doing it _JS_ messes up some of my attribute values. Please see the answer below. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a way to call any custom python function on a collection using [parallel_scan](https://api.mongodb.com/python/2.7.1/api/pymongo/collection.html?highlight=parallel_scan#pymongo.collection.Collection.parallel_scan) in PyMongo.

```
def process_text(cursor):
    for row in cursor.batch_size(200):
        # Any complex preprocessing here...
        split_text = row['text'].split()

        db.collection.update_one({'_id': row['_id']}, 
                                 {'$set': {'split_text': split_text, 
                                           'num_words': len(split_text) }},
                                 upsert=True)


def preprocess(num_threads=4):

    # Get up to max 'num_threads' cursors.
    cursors = db.collection.parallel_scan(num_threads)
    threads = [threading.Thread(target=process_text, args=(cursor,)) for cursor in cursors]

    for thread in threads:
        thread.start()

    for thread in threads:
        thread.join()
```

This is not really faster than `cursor.forEach` (but not that slow either), but it helps me execute any arbitrarily complex python code and save the results from within Python itself.

Also if I have an array of `ints` in one of the attributes, doing `cursor.forEach` converts them to `floats` which I don't want. So I preferred this way.

But I would be glad to know if there're any better ways than this :)

Comment: Since Python doesn't support true parallelism, it can only be as fast as `cursor.forEach` and should be slower in the usual case.

Answer (score 0):

It is quite unlikely that it will ever be efficient to do this kind of thing in python. This is because the document would have to make a round trip and go through the python function on the client machine.

In your example code, you are passing the result of a function to a mongodb `update` query, which won't work. You can't run any python code inside mongodb queries on the db server.

As the [answer to you linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14423151/3271558) suggests, this type of action has to be performed in the mongo shell.  e.g:

```
db.collection.find().snapshot().forEach(
    function (elem) {
        splitLength = elem.text.split(" ").length
        db.collection.update(

            {
                _id: elem._id
            },
            {
                $set: {
                    split: splitLength 
                }
            }
        );
    }
);
```